# Regex picks up one match, but fails to see another

Tags: c#, windows, .net

I have a regex that should* pickup to results in a string:

Input string:

```
Vmid        Name                             File                           Guest OS       Version   Annotation
3      TinyCore Linux   [datastore1] TinyCore Linux/TinyCore Linux.vmx   otherLinuxGuest   vmx-08
4      Debain6          [datastore1] Debain6/Debain6.vmx                 ubuntu64Guest     vmx-08
```

Regex:

```
[]][ A-Za-z /.]+.vmx [ ]
```

The regex matches the folowing part of the string:

```
] TinyCore Linux/TinyCore Linux.vmx
```

but is should also match:

```
] Debain6/Debain6.vmx
```

My code is as follows:

```
private void regexTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("[]][ A-Za-z /.]+.vmx [ ]");
    MatchCollection match = regex.Matches(input);

    foreach (Match matchvalue in match)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(matchvalue.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you lost digits `\d`

your regex: `[]][\dA-Za-z /.]+.vmx [ ]`

and my upgrade `\][\dA-Za-z\s/.]+\.vmx`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like that, the following expression will match every type character between ] and .vmx

```
\](.+?)\.vmx
```

or for pattern like ][word]/[word].vmx try

```
\](.+)?\/(.+?)\.vmx
```

or general (.) replaced with specific match characters

```
\]([a-z0-9A-Z-_\s\/]+)?\.vmx
```

You can easily test regular expression output via http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

[image]

Comment: your regex match `] TinyCore Linux/TinyCore Linux.vmx   otherLinuxGuest   vmx`

Comment: may be you test with `] TinyCore Linux/TinyCore Linux.vmx`? with full string your regex is not work

Comment: specifically checked - does not work, share link does not work too

Comment: look on your screenshot, user1559618 have only last 3 rows, but your match wrong in last rows

Comment: you wrong again =) dot in regex is any symbol, and regex match somethink like this `]  vmx` and it happend in column 'version' will have `]`

Comment: i used (.) for general matching, i added specific match.

Comment: You did not understand me i said about last dot, which have not shield